# recursive function: non-recursive form possible?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, recursion

Can the following recursive function be converted to a non-recursive form?

$$f(x,c,\ell)=\frac{c-c^\ell}{1-c}+(c-2)\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\ell-1}f(x,c,k)$$

$$f(x,c,1)=c$$

$$c= \text{constant}$$

$$\ell=\text{length}$$

If so, where do I start?

Comment: What is the role played by $x$? It is easy to see by induction that, since $f(x,c,1)$ is constant in $x$, also $f(x,c,\ell)$ is constant in $x$ for every $\ell$.

Comment: Perhaps I have made it more complicated than it need be, so should be:
$f(c,\ell)=\frac{c-c^\ell}{1-c}+(c-2)\sum_{k=1}^{\ell-1}f(c,k)$

Comment: EDIT: I claim $f(c,\ell)=c^\ell - c(c-1)^\ell$ for every $\ell \geq 3$. I am trying to fix the details of induction...

Answer (score 0):

I use $n$ instead of $\ell$, hope you do not mind. Let's prove by (strong) induction that, for $n \geq 2$, it holds $f(c,n) = c^n - c(c-1)^{n-2}$. For $n=2$ it is clear, since $f(c,2) = c+(c-2)c = c^2-c$. If the assumption holds for every $2 \leq j \leq n$, then
\begin{align*}
f(c,n+1) &= \frac{c^{n+1}-c}{c-1} + (c-2)\sum_{j=1}^n f(c,j) = \frac{c^{n+1}-c}{c-1} + (c-2)\left [ \sum_{j=2}^n \left (c^j - c(c-1)^{j-2}\right ) + c \right ] \\ &= \frac{c^{n+1}-c}{c-1} + (c-2)\sum_{j=2}^n c^j -c(c-2)\sum_{j=2}^n (c-1)^{j-2} + (c-2)c \\ &= \frac{c^{n+1}-c}{c-1} + (c-2)\sum_{j=0}^n c^j -(c-2)(1+c) - c(c-2)\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} (c-1)^j + (c-2)c \\ &= \frac{c^{n+1}-c}{c-1} + (c-2)\frac{c^{n+1}-1}{c-1} - c(c-2)\frac{(c-1)^{n-1}-1}{c-2} -c+2 \\ &= \frac{c^{n+1}-c+c^{n+2}-2c^{n+1}-c+2+2c-2}{c-1} - c(c-1)^{n-1} = c^{n+1} - c(c-1)^{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand the induction, but I get something quote different:

Comment: $f(c,n+1)=\frac{c^{(n+1)}-c}{1-c}+(c-2)\sum_{j=2}^nf(c,n)$

Comment: $f(c,n+1)=\frac{c^{(n+1)}-c}{c-1}+(c-2)(\frac{c^n-1}{c-1}+(c-2)\sum_{j=2}^{n-1}f(c,j))$

Comment: In the induction of course I used for $f(c,j)$ the expression $c^j-c(c-1)^{j-2}$ (induction hypothesis). But for $j=1$ this does not hold, so I added the term $(c-2)c$. I will try to edit the answer and make it clearer.

Comment: Considering c=14 and n=3, f(c,n)=378:

Comment: $f(c,n)=\frac{c^n-c}{c-1}+(c-2)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(c,k)$

Comment: $f(14,3)=\frac{14^3-14}{14-1}+(14-2)\sum_{k=1}^{3-1}f(14,k)$

Comment: $f(14,3)=210+12\sum_{k=1}^{2}f(14,k)$

Comment: $f(14,3)=210+12(f(14,1)+f(14,2))$

Comment: as $f(c,1)=0, f(c,2)=c$ then $f(14,1)=0, f(14,2)=14$, so:

Comment: $f(14,3)=210+12(0+14)=378$

Comment: So, for all $n$ then $f(c,n)=c^n-c(c-1)^{n-1}$ raising to the $n-1$ power rather than $n$ or $n-2$.

Comment: In your question you said $f(c,1) = c$. So $f(14,1) = 14$, $f(14,2) = 14 + 12*14 = 14^2 - 14$ as I proved.